# Proving $Ext_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(A,B)$ is a torsion-free abelian group, given that $A$ is divisible and $B$ is torsion-free

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

I have been trying to prove the following:

Let $A,B$ be abelian groups. If $A$ is *divisible* and $B$ is torsion-free, then the group $Ext_{\mathbb{Z}}^1(A,B)$ is torsion-free.

So, I study homological algebra and in my class we have come as far as to define the $Ext$ functor. I have tried proving this result using long exact sequences, since I Know that $Ext_{\mathbb{Z}}^i(A,B)=0$ for all $i \geq 2$ and all abelian groups $A,B$. After that, I am completely stumped. I should also mention that in my class we did not define the $Tor$ functor and we defined the $Ext$ using projective resolutions.
I tried looking in the following books:

*Basic Homological Algebra* by M. Scott Osborne

*An Introduction to Homological Algebra* by Joseph J. Rotman

to no avail. Of course, it is possible that the answer is in one of these books and I may have missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is divisible, the map $n:A\to A$ is surjective for any nonzero integer $n$.  There is thus a short exact sequence $$0\to K\to  A\stackrel{n}\to A\to 0$$ which gives a long exact sequence $$0\to \operatorname{Hom}(A,B)\stackrel{n}\to\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)\to \operatorname{Hom}(K,B)\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B) \stackrel{n}\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(K,B)\to 0.$$

But since $K$ is the kernel of multiplication by $n$, it is $n$-torsion, so $\operatorname{Hom}(K,B)=0$ since $B$ is torsion-free.  Exactness of the sequence above now says that $n:\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ is injective.  Since $n$ is an arbitrary nonzero integer, this says that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Why didn't you mention $K$ before using it ?

Comment: I assume $K$ just stands for kernel of the surjection $n$.